# Show div on scroll only once

Tags: jquery, scroll, conditional-statements, show

I've got this DIV I want to show when a user scrolls via jQuery. That works (I modified a 'sticky NAV' script). I want it to disappear from view after 4 seconds so I added a removeClass after a delay. It all works, but I'd like to make sure this only happens once (it is a tip for users they can swipe left and right).

Here is the HTML

```
     <div id="inhoudMobiel">

        <div id="swipetip"></div>

        <div id="swipetipanker"></div>

    </div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var stickyCount = 'aan';
console.log(stickyCount);
var stickyNavTop = $('#swipetipanker').offset().top;  

var stickyNav = function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (stickyCount = 'aan') {
        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
            $('body').addClass('sticky');
            setTimeout(function(){$('body').removeClass('sticky')}, 4000);
            var stickyCount = 'uit';
            console.log(stickyCount);
        }
        }
    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {
            stickyNav();
    });
});
```

I added the console log lines to see what happens, it works like I would expect, the console logs 'aan' once, and after the first scroll it keeps logging 'uit'. But still the DIV keeps appearing on every scroll over and over.

After the first answer, I modified my code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var stickyNavTop = $('#swipetipanker').offset().top;  

var stickyNav = function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
            $('body').addClass('sticky');
            setTimeout(function(){$('body').removeClass('sticky')}, 4000);
            var stickyCount = 0;
            console.log(stickyCount);
            }
        };

var stickyCount = 1;
console.log(stickyCount);

if (stickyCount === 1) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            stickyNav();
    });
}
});
```

Replaced the 'on' and 'off' text with 0 and 1 (more logical), and mainly improved the comparator to actually compare in stead of re-setting the variable. Still the DIV I want to show only once appears every single scroll movement. In the console, you will see one '1', followed by a series of zeroes. So the resetting of the variable works, but the comparator doesn't. Also the zeroes keep coming as you scroll, so basically the scroll detection keeps working even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you alter your code as below, it will keep it from running multiple times In your if statement to detect whether `stickyCount` was changed from its initial value, you were using `=` which is an assignment operator, which changed the value of `stickyCount` instead of comparing it. Changing it to `===` makes sure that you are doing a proper comparison, which is what you are wanting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stickyCount = 'aan',
        firstRun = true;
    console.log(stickyCount);
    var stickyNavTop = $('#swipetipanker').offset().top;  

    var stickyNav = function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (stickyCount === 'aan') {
            if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
                $('body').addClass('sticky');
                setTimeout(function(){$('body').removeClass('sticky')}, 4000);
                stickyCount = 'uit';
                console.log(stickyCount);
            }
        }
    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid of me not to look up the comparing operator, what you say makes sense. However, I still behaves the same. I put the 'if' statement around the '$(window).scroll' function because there's no need to keep the scroll detection going after you don't need it anymore, but still my div appears on every scroll movement. In the console, you will get the initial counter followed by a series of 'after first used' counters, so that works sort of, but still the div keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this now in maybe a not so elegant manner, but it does what I need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var stickyNavTop = $('#swipetipanker').offset().top;

var stickyNav = function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
        $('body').addClass('sticky');
        setTimeout(function(){$('body').removeClass('sticky')}, 4000);
        setTimeout(function(){$('#swipetip').remove()}, 4000);
    }
};

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    }); 
});
```

I just remove the "swipetip" DIV from the DOM after it has been shown once. Not so elegant because the scroll listener stays intact listening to nothing but it does the trick.